# Learning Angular - is this the right way to link a div to a service?

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning Angular and I'm wondering if there is a better way to link this directive to my service?

Mostly I'm wondering if storing a Guid as an Id in the model and then referring to that id in my service is a good way to link the directive and the service?  Or is there a more "Angular" way to do this?

Directive:

```
myApp.directive("myDialog", ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: "="
        },
        template: "<div id='dialog_{{model.dialogId}}' ng-include='model.templateUrl' style='display: none'></div>",
        replace: true
}]);
```

Service:

```
myApp.service("myDialogSvc", function () {
    // This will be called by the controller
    this.init = function (template) {
        var model = {};

        model.template = template;

        var id = newGuid();  // Gets a new Guid -- defined elsewhere
        model.dialogId = id;

        return model;
    }

    this.open = function (model) {

        $("#dialog_" + model.dialogId).dialog({
            modal: true
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be factory pattern. I have seen people using this approach in angular, imho, a decent appraoch